# How to check if file exists and executable from Java, on Unix?

Tags: java, unix

I'm trying to check if a file exists in Unix, from within a Java process.

I'm struggling with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`
The command I'm trying to run is `test -x $VAR/path/to/file`, note the Unix variable inside the path.

The command returns either 0 or 1, but I don't know how to get the indication for that from within Java.

What I'm currently doing is:

```
String cmd = "test -x $VAR/filename";
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
int exitCode = proc.waitFor();
```

I can also add `;echo $?` to the command, which will print the 0/1 value, but I don't know how to get the output of the command.

Comment: A combination of `File.exists()` and `System.getenv()` should do the trick without the need of an external process. Your bonus prize is that this solution is also platform-independent.

Comment: Process class has also two methods to get output: [Process.getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and  [Process.getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Java.io.File class
It has the methods `canExecute()` and `exists()`

Example:

```
//Create new File
File file = new File("C:/test/testFile.exe");

//Check if file exists
if (file.exists()) {
    System.out.println("The File Exists");

    //Check if file is executable
    if (file.canExecute()) {
        System.out.println("The File is executable");
    }
}
```

Comment: And for env. variables, we can use `System.getenv(VAR)`

Comment: Please don't use ` == true`.  Just use the return value from the methods.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [`File#exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) and [`File#canExecute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#canExecute()) for checking its existance and checking if it is *executable*

Comment: Actually `canExecute()` should be enough according to the javadoc as it also checks for existance.

Comment: @Marvin - Well, not exactly, what if the file is present but is not *executable*?

Comment: @TheLostMind: I read the question as "I want to check both requirements and don't care which one fails". If the difference matters, then you need `exists()` as well, of course.